# Is it required to restart the IIS after adding a default document?

Tags: iis-7.5

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question but hopefully there is an IIS expert here. I was wondering if by adding a default document in the IIS, stricly requires an IIS restart.
I know that some changes, for instance in the Web configuration file does not.But just wanted to confirm what is the approach in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed. No need to restart IIS. Just tested myself in IIS 7.5.